# How could i emit events to a cloud server and listen to it from another network via the url of the website of the cloud server

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, socket.io

So i'm hoping if there is a way for me to emit events to cloud server by typing it into the text field of html and listen to that event from another network via nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you create a socket event on a server. You can listen to that event from anywhere using socket.io-client.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io.connect("http://server_url");

 socket.on("event", () => {
        //do something
      });
```

Check this documentation https://socket.io/docs/v4/ server and client